Creating an Android library Module for Common-code sources
After consulting with others on S/O and a consultant I work with, I am now convinced the correct way for exposing a common-code base between two app-flavors, is with an Android Library Module.  So, that basically means I can take the following sources from $TOP/app/src/main/* and move them to $TOP/common-src/src/main/*

all JNI code under ./cpp/
all kotlin+java code under ./java/com/company/mypackage/*

Here is what I'm not sure about:  do I still need $TOP/app/src/main/ , or can I continue w/o it?
Thanks, Charles.
